# Proof of Heine Borel without proof by contradiction( closed and bounded $\iff$ compact direction)

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, alternative-proof

My question is simple as the title shows. Is there any proof that directly proves the Heine-Borel Theorem. 
Thanks.

Comment: I think the heart of the problem is finding a proof that $[0,1]$ is compact that doesn't use contradiction. From there you can work your way to Heine-Borel by general topological principles that don't (I think) use arguments by contradiction.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any proof that shows [0,1] is compact without using proof by contradiction?